# CSS: Text moves in window on mouse pressing and moving

Tags: html, css

I have this input:

```css
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-top-color: #b3b3b3;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px 8px 5px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  width: 110px;
  height: 24px !important;
  line-height: 14px !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input tabindex="2" type="text" size="9" maxlength="2" id="INPUT_1" />
```

It is OK in all browsers except IE11. If I push mouse button inside `input` and then move the mouse up or down, text in input moves too. But I want text to be static and non-moving in this case.

How to prevent this behaviour in Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: Looks like a ton of options - why so much css - do you want to achive a hyperdimensional look - I don't understand the reason for so much blown up css. Please explain what your overall goal is. Thanks. In css - more properties doesn't necesarrily mean "better".

Comment: That's probably the largest stack of css values I've seen on an element.

Comment: @user2521387 Sorry, just copied from SnappySnippet for the first time. Cleaned up CSS snippet.